# org-attach from a Dired buffer

Tags: org-mode, dired

I want to be able to attach files to a sub-tree from a Dired buffer. The org-mode manual gives instructions on how to do this in the link below:

https://orgmode.org/manual/Attachments.html

At the bottom of the article they have two pieces of code that one is to insert into one's init file to get this to work. However, neither set of lines work. I have tried them and they generate errors.

My goal is to be able to attach multiple files at one time to my org headlines. At present I use C-c C-a m which attaches a file at a time.

Comment: The manual contained an extra parenthesis (fixed in Org's 1a16155d9).  Try removing it.  Also, `org-attach-dired-to-subtree` isn't autoloaded (it now is, as of Org's c6d37c6eb), so you'll need to make sure to load `org-attach`.

Comment: Thank you. Loading org-attach made the difference.